# DRBD 9 internal-metada vs makefs

Tags: drbd

Here are the steps I followed to create a two node DRBD 9 setup:

1. Create LVM
2. On each node created internal meta-data with `drbdadm create-md 'resourcename'`
3. On each node brought the resource up with `drbdadm up 'resourcename'`
4. Prompted one with `drbdadm primary --force 'resourcename'` as the primary node
5. Made it secondary again `drbdadm secondary 'resourcename'`
6. Formatted it `makefs.ext4 /dev/drbd1`

My question is, why does step 6 not wipe out the internal meta-data from step 2?

Comment: It should not do that. Can you share your DRBD configuration with us?

Comment: @MattKereczman Sorry, there's a typo in my question. It should be "how come does step 6 **NOT** wipe out the internal meta-data from step 2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using internal metadata, DRBD reserves a small amount of space, about 32 MiB per 1 TiB, at the *end* of its backing disk. That's how DRBD keeps track of things like blocks out of sync and the characteristics of it's peer's backing disk(s). This is why your DRBD device is slightly smaller than the disk you're using to back DRBD.